# How do I prevent Memory leaks when using JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a `JFrame` containing a button. When the button is clicked, it opens a window containing a `JTextPane` with a lot of text.

1. At the begining, the application takes up 35 mb memory.
2. When new window is opened, the application takes up ~200 mb worth of memory.
3. When the new window is closed, the application takes up ~120 mb worth of memory.

```java
package main;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MemoryLeakTest {
    public void start(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JButton button = new JButton("Create new window");
        button.addActionListener(l->{
            createWindow();
        });
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void createWindow(){
        window w = new window();
        w.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MemoryLeakTest().start();
    }
}

class window extends JFrame {
    private JTextPane textPane;

    public window() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);
        textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setText(extremelyLongText());
        add(textPane);
        System.out.println("New window created!");
    }

    public String extremelyLongText() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++, builder.append("\n"))
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++, builder.append("a")) ;
        return new String(builder);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
        textPane.setText("");
        System.gc();
        textPane= null;
        System.gc();
    }
}
```

I have overridden the dispose method to set this `JTextPane` to null. I expected the memory consumption to go back down to 35 mb, but it drops to only 120 mb. Why is this happening? Is the string in `JTextPane` not getting Garbage Collected?
How do i ensure that memory is freed up whenever I use a `JTextPane`?

Edit:
I am using jdk 16 on Windows 10 to test this, and i am seeing the memory usage on task manager

Comment: gc can starting at the moment when/after EDT returns false, btw all toplevel contaners aren't garbadged, only its graphics, you can reuse those object until current jvm instance lives,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like there is no memory leak happening.
Running the program under jconsole revealed that the heap memory does return to original size after closing the new windows:

[image]

However, the non heap memory increases significantly when the 1st window is created:

[image]

the non heap memory stays pretty much the same even after creating the 2nd window, or even a 3rd, so i guess there isn't much of a problem here.

I am not aware of any way to release non-heap memory, but i guess it is safe to say that the above code is correct, and there is no memory leak happening.
(Although only the last System.gc() call is enough)

Answer (score 1):

Don't expect System.gc() to force a gc. Some jvm's don't even do anything when it is called. The jvm  is allowed to do gc whenever it it decides to.

Comment: But the question remains, how would i clear the memory after getting rid of this new window? How do i properly dispose this window so i can free up all resources taken up by it?

Comment: You don't have to. Once it is closed and your code doesn't have any references to it anymore the memory for it can be reclaimed  by the jvm.

Comment: Also, the `System.gc()` command is still doing *something*. When using openjdk 16, if i close this new window along with `System.gc()` , it comes down to 120 mb, if i didn't use `System.gc()` along with it, it would stay at 200 mb.  So a garbage collection *is* taking place, so I suspect some object in my code isn't eligible for garbage collection. Any idea of what to do?

Comment: You can't expect that call to reclaim all memory.  It can reclaim some or nothing or do it at a later time. It is up to the garbage collector to decide and it is jvm specific.

Comment: So I am guessing the code above is still correct and there is no memory leak. I just tested it again, and it stays at 120 mb even after creating and closing many windows, so obviously, no memory is leaking. But another question emerges - how do i get it back to 35 mb? Or, is that impossible?

Comment: Note that when the window is created a native call allocate resources that not are in the heap. When the window is closed those resources are deallocated and that has nothing to do with gc.

Comment: There's no way for you to force the memory to get back to your initial memory. Just trust the garbage collector.

Comment: I really need to know what to do to get it back to its original memory consumption of 35 mb, even if there is no memory leaks happening. I have an application which displays a lot of text, and it gets really heavy if there is a lot of text. Even if i `dispose()` it correctly, it doesn't return to its original memory consumption.

Comment: there really is no way, huh. Well, that was a bummer....

Comment: Actually,  check the parameters for your jvm, maybe you can configure it to be more eager.